# Ember and Sails Deployment

Tags: jenkins, docker, vagrant, travis-ci

I am making a web app with a team of 5 using Ember and Sails. The frontend will be written using Ember and the backend will be a RESTful API written using Sails. Both will be stored in separate, public GitHub repositories. I was planning on setting up a single VPS on DigitalOcean to host the database (MongoDB), backend, and frontend. We don't have the money to have separate servers and the production setup is really just to demo the project to professors.

Does anyone have a recomendation on a good workflow from development to production? There are so many options: Vagrant, Docker, Travis, Jenkins; I don't know what to do. Thanks.